# Ionic FTP plugin - FTP plug in upload to specific folder

Tags: ftp, ionic2

I’m trying the ftp plug in to upload a file and the upload to the root ( www.mydomain.com ) is ok

This works ok :

```
this.fTP.upload(imageURI,’myfile.jpg’ )
```

But I need upload to www.mydomain.com/www/somefolder.

I’m trying :

```
this.fTP.upload(imageURI,’/Web/somefolder/myfile.jpg’ )
```

But got can’t find the path specified error.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with :

```
this.fTP.upload(imageURI,’Web/somefolder/myfile.jpg’ )
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a same issue got:-

File upload failed

```
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException [code=550, message= Can't change directory to /upload/images/: No such file or directory]

var dataimage =  file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.hootel.booking/cache/httpsimg1cfcdnclubaea6aea9ebd927206461cdfb666bcd800da6.jpg

/upload/images/ :- is server path
```

my code is

```
this.fTP.upload(dataimage, '/upload/images/');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after some Rnd.

dataimage // its your full file path.
and the 2nd parameter is ftp folder and file name. file name is same in the file path.

this.fTP.upload(dataimage, '/upload/httpsimg1cfcdnclubaea6aea9ebd927206461cdfb666bcd800da6.jpg')